# Why the background isn't right?

Tags: java, background, panel

I am trying to make a java game. And I am confronted with a problem:

```
 public void setUp () {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Key test");
    //MyDrawPanel4 dp4 = new MyDrawPanel4();
    //frame.setContentPane(dp4);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible (true);
    
    JPanel p = new JPanel ();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//why this sentence is necessary
    p.addKeyListener (this);
    p.add (dp);     
    frame.getContentPane().add(p);
            frame.pack();
    
    
}
```

And the result is a small snack.[image]

I want to use dp4 as the backgound of game. But what actually happen is [image]

So my question is :

1.Why this happen?

2.How to make background of game?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: what I really mean is the two black body of the snack disappear, and it cannot move when I press the key (I use the key listener to fulfill it).

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("arjun");  
        JPanel panel=new MyDrawPanel();  
        panel.setSize(100,100);  
        image=new ImageIcon("C:/raptor.jpeg").getImage();  // use this
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);  
        frame.setSize(300,300);  
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Key test");
//MyDrawPanel4 dp4 = new MyDrawPanel4();
//frame.setContentPane(dp4);
```

-->FIRST

```
**Panel p = new Panel ();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//it's a container
p.addKeyListener (this);
p.add (dp);     
frame.getContentPane().add(p);**
```

-->AFTER

```
frame.setSize (300, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible (true);
```

The image that you try to load is too large.
When you load an image, you MUST resize it to Image (or simile) control sizes.